# LapTop Cursor path is not stable when using touch pad with AC power supply

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

I faced this problem in our new factory office. When the AC power charger is connected to the laptop I cannot use touch pad properly due to is beginning to jump/slower/jittering but not smoothly moving. When the power supply removed and laptop runs by battery power, it becomes normal. I suspect the power supply. Is it bad earthing or harmonics in the power system?

Comment: Does it do the same thing when using a different wall outlet, or in a different room or building (or even neighbourhood), or a different AC power charger?

Comment: It is same in all outlets in same building with same UPS power supply. But it is normal in other buildings with separate power supply.

Comment: That's interesting. Maybe it's the UPS, I don't know exactly how but if it's being used everywhere there's problems, that's a strong correlation. Or that building itself, but I'm hoping it's just the UPS, they're a lot easier to replace that building wiring.